# How to automatically create a missing folder?

Tags: java, file-io

In java, I need to write a string into a new file, like 'c:\test\upload\myfile.txt', if the 'upload' folder is not existing, it will automatically create it. how to do it ? Apache Commons IO has this API ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
File file = new File(...);
file.mkdirs(); //for several levels, without the "s" for one level
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
fileWriter.write("...");
```

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary parent directories.
>
> **Returns:**
>   true if and only if the directory was created, along with all necessary parent directories; false otherwise

See [File.mkdirs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) and  [File.mkdir()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29)

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Actual writing to the file is not in the answer you mean? I assumed that wasn't the problem considering the title of the question. Update: added file writing to the example.

Answer (score 10):

In **addition** to the accepted answer, since the question also mentioned the library **Apache Common IO**, I report in the following a solution by using this nice library:

```
File file = new File("...  the directory path ..."); 
FileUtils.forceMkdir(file);
```

This solution uses the class [`FileUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html), from package `org.apache.commons.io` and the method [`forceMkdir`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#forceMkdir%28java.io.File%29), that "*Makes a directory, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories*".

Comment: This solution will force you to catch exceptions (`IOException` if you pass an existing file).

Answer (score 3):

```
new File(fileToSave.getParent()).mkdirs();
```

It returns a boolean to check if the making succeeded (will fail if the disk is full or if a file exists with the name 'upload', etc)